# Why doesn't FutureProvider have a dispose callback?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Managing an object's complete lifecycle via `Provider` is possible:

```dart
Provider<LocalStorageManager>(
  create: (context) => LocalStorageManager(),
  dispose: (context, obj) => obj.dispose(),
),
```

However, if the object has to be asynchronously initialized, we have to use `FutureProvider`:

```dart
FutureProvider<LocalStorageManager>(
  create: (context) async => await LocalStorageManager().initialize(),
),
```

If `FutureProvider` has no `dispose` callback, how should I dispose of `LocalStorageManager`?

Furthermore, what is the difference with `FutureProvider.value` if the lifecycle is not managed?